# Using variable registered in playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to code a playbook where the PID of a remote process is registered as variable and then I execute other shell commands against that PID:

```
- name: capture remote pid
  hosts: web.servers
  tasks:
          - name: capture PID
            shell: ps ax | grep eap | cut -d " " -f1 
            register: pid 
          - name: print PID information
            shell: ps -ef | grep {{ pid.stdout }}
```

So from this simple playbook I'd expect to print the process information from the remote PID, however nothing at all is printed:

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.3.9.155                 : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pgrep` instead of grepping and cutting the `ps ax` results.

You should also consider what happens when you have several PIDs matching the process name. `pid.stdout` will contain a multi-line output. Instead you should iterate over `pid.stdout_lines`.

Finally, you need to display the results, if you want to see them. `ps -ef | grep {{ pid.stdout }}` in your task might be run correctly and redirect its output to stdout, but Ansible does not include the output in its log (on the screen). It will also become a list as you iterate in the `print PID information` task.

```
- name: capture remote pid
  hosts: web.servers
  tasks:
     - name: capture PID
       shell: pgrep eap
       register: pid 

     - name: print PID information
       shell: ps -ef | grep {{ item }}
       with_items: "{{ pid.stdout_lines }}"
       register: second_pid

     - name: display the results in Ansible log (on the screen)
       debug:
         var: second_pid
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. Just a note, I had to change the last line to "debug: var=second_pid" otherwise a syntax error is raised. Now it works as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't see a syntax error in the last line, neither my Ansible does. Your syntax is also correct, but there is no reason to fail on the YAML-one.